# npm i npm Error npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 16441

Tags: npm, npm-install

Actually I was trying to install the dependencies for my class project which I fetched from my team's GitHub repository but I am facing error and it keep on returning error with message:

> npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 16441

Any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove package.lock file
and run `npm install`